# Haskell on MAC LION

Tags: haskell

First of all, thank you for looking at this. I am a newbie to programming( I can program Java and Python)

I am gonna ask some really trivial questions.
How do i install the "extra " of Haskell on my mac? My situation is that i got ghci running, i am following the tutorial from my Terminal http://learnyouahaskell.com/introduction

I downloaded GHC
Xcode
Emacs(not working, more explanation below)

But i would like to have something like they use in their examples, a text editor that help me write in .hs and support the programming language. I tried to download Emacs but i couldn't find "haskell" as supported language, and i have no idea how to install it so it works together with my GHC. Also, i don't think the tutorial says a lot about Cabal. How do i access it? If i just go in and type "cabal install" or just "cabal" it just gives me "not in scope" as an answer.

Maybe i misunderstood cabal? it isn't something you "access" as such?

Thanks for checking my post out. I look forward to functional programming!( i am a mathematician :) )

Comment: I use emacs for Haskell and it's great, I use haskell-mode (referenced by Yuras) alongside ghc-mod[https://github.com/kazu-yamamoto/ghc-mod].  ghc-mod takes a bit more setup than haskell-mode but is well worth it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the Apple developer tools installed already, you can look at a package manager like e.g. homebrew (see at [Link](https://brew.sh/) for installation). Then in a terminal you type

```
brew install ghc haskell-platform
```

and it will take care of everything, dependencies etc. You will get ghc, ghci, cabal, everything at once. It will put things in `/usr/local/` so you might not even have to edit your `$PATH` ...

For editing, Aquamacs (download at http://aquamacs.org/) supports Haskell out of the box, and is very Mac-friendly.

Comment: Hi.

Indeed yes i downloaded the Haskell-platform.

I downloaded the homebrew, it wen't well, but when i did "Install ghc haskell-platform" it downloaded GHC, and then started installing, but midways it interrupted with install failure. Maybe its because i already installed the haskell platform.

How do i see the directory where i installed these things? That is a really stupid question in windows at least, but i actually can't find the folders when i search for "ghc" or "cabal" with the mac "Finder".
Oh and I'm sorry, but could you elaborate on how you configure Aquamacs? I have it installed.

Comment: Homebrew puts its stuff in /usr/local/Cellar/<package-name> (which is invisible in the Finder, because it would frighten the typical Mac user to know that /usr exists, apparently). `brew ls` will tell you the list of installed packages. As for the GHC you previously installed, I don't know where it would be.

Comment: About Aquamacs: I had nothing to do to get syntax coloring and so on in it, just open a `.hs` file and see what happens. The rest (compiling etc) I do on the console, it is very likely that you can do fancy stuff within Emacs (like interactive REPL in a buffer) but I did not try.

Comment: wonderfull. Aquamacs is working now atleast. thank you! -1 to problems.

Answer (score 3):

Did you install ghc directly from http://www.haskell.org/ghc/ ? Usually it is better to install [haskell platform](http://hackage.haskell.org/platform/) as suggested in the tutorial. It includes `cabal` already.

If you used haskell platform, then try to find where `cabal` is installed and add the directory into your $PATH variable. I think you can fire a bug if platform installer for Mac doesn't install `cabal` in usual location.

(Note: AFAIK haskell platform installer is broken for new MacOS, it contains hardcoded path to xcode. But it is simple to find and fix)

Check out [haskell mode for emacs](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Haskell_mode_for_Emacs). I don't use emacs, so the link is the only I can suggest, sorry.